# Font that is being rendered on Android is not getting rendered on iOS even though I've followed all the steps from the most popular guides

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've followed the following steps in order to use custom fonts on Android and iOS.

1. Create the following folder that contains all fonts `src/assets/fonts`.
2. Fonts are named `fakt_pro_normal.otf` and `fakt_pro_medium.otf`.
3. Have a `react-native.config.js` file which contains the following:
4. ```
   module.exports = {
       project: {
           ios: {},
           android: {},
       },
       assets: ['./src/assets/fonts'],
   };
   ```
5. Linked using `npx react-native-asset`
6. Add the fonts in the build phases - copy bundle resources

However while this works on Android, it does not work on iOS and I am not sure why because it seems I've followed all possible steps.

Comment: Try checkout the example ```npx create-expo-app -e with-custom-font```